# I cannot make Java accept a keyboard input string

Tags: java, input

I would like to know how to get a keyboard response in my java program to work and continue with the game as normal.

I realize the code is a little messy and an array might suit better, but for this instance I would like only answers about keyboard inputs.

The game works well enough until it reaches the if and if else statement. Then I really don't know how to fix it.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class blackjack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String money;
        String name;
        String hiscore;
        String h;
        String s;

        int card1 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card2 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card3 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card4 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card5 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card6 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card7 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card8 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card9 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card10 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card11 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card12 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);
        int card13 = 1 + r.nextInt(11);

        int total1 = card2 + card3;
        int total2 = total1 + card4;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Blackjack ! ");
        System.out.println("Score as close to 21 without going over to win ");
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
        System.out.println("Let's play some BlackJack!");

        System.out.println("The dealer shows: \n\t\t" + card1);
        System.out.println("Your first card is: \n\t\t " + card2);
        System.out.println("Your second card is: \n\t\t" + card3);
        System.out.println("giving you a total of " + total1);
        System.out.println("Would you like to (H)it or (S)tick?");
        if h = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your next card is " + card4);
        System.out.println("Giving you a new total of: " + total2);
        if else s = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("your final score is: "total1);
    }
}
```

Comment: That `if` and that `if else` are not valid java code and will not compile. Remove them. And Vincent, then i recommend you to read something about the if and other flow control statement, because i don't think you can go much further without knowing how the if works.

Comment: Ah yes, that seems to have done it, Thanks!
These are my first baby steps in to java and obviously I don't entirely know what I'm doing. This is all trial and error to me. 

My biggest problem so far is I can't understand what the errors are when I compile the program.

Comment: You can check out "Thinking in Java" or "Head First Java" if you need something to learn the basic of the language fast, it will be a lot easier after that!

Comment: So, when you ask questions here, it's best not to give us *all* of the code, but just the code that you're pretty sure shows the question.  In this case, the lines that start with "if"... aren't Java, they're not going to work at all; you'll want to look that up first.

Answer (score 0):

That `if` (and `if-else`) statement is ***broken***.  It's not valid syntax.  Correct syntax would be:

```
if(h = keyboard.nextLine());
```

Note that I said that was correct *syntax*, but that will definitely not do what you want it to do.  It seems like what you want to do is check against predetermined strings "h" and "s".

Store the variable off somewhere, then do the comparison.  Remember that to compare Strings in Java, you need to use .equals().

```
String response = keyboard.nextLine();
if("h".equals(response)) {
    // perform operations here
} else if("s".equals(response)) {
    // perform operations here
}
```